# How to run spritesheet animation frames from server

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have a new project in which I am trying to do the following:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abc.com/images/AnimBear.plist"];

NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com/images/AnimBear.png"];

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:imageName];;
```

My animation frames are on the server and I want to run those frames from the server. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the files and save them in the app's documents directory. Check out the [source code](https://github.com/LearnCocos2D/LearnCocos2D/tree/master/Cocos2D-UpdateFilesFromWebServer) for my [Cocos2D Webcam Viewer tutorial](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/01/download-modified-files-web-server-cocos2d-webcam-viewer/) which does exactly that.

Comment: thanks for help me I am another problem it is possible that can you help me in that problem , my problem is that I want to move an object from one point to another (just like flight control HD game) any idea ?

Comment: I have some problem the problem is that I have 15 frames each of 2 or 3mb If I use background thread of downloading images from server that there may be memory issue, or I download one file then run animation then download second file then download then there will be jerking in the animation , is there is any best way of dealing these animation frames??